# Mercurial: Is possible to avoid any proxy settings?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, mercurial

What I want to know is if there are any chances to avoid any kind of proxy setting specified through environmental variable (e.g. etc/envinroment), in order to let mercurial(v4.2) on Ubuntu 16.04 communicate directly with the host specified in the hgrc file inside the repo.

I tried with `no_proxy` directive in `etc/environment`, and in the `.hgrc` file (both general and local to my repo).
I even tried to remove proxy entries from my OS, and incredibly mercurial still uses it:

```
pulling from http://boo.baa/repo
using http://boo.baa/repo
proxying through http://10.0.8.251:800
http auth: user jdoe, password not set
sending capabilities command
abort: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out
```

The only whay I found to get this works is to reboot my OS without any proxy settings, which is absurd to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add this to **.hgrc**:

```
[http_proxy]
no = bitbucket.org
```

About the **no_proxy** setting, you should get the same result.
Like this:

```
no_proxy="bitbucket.org" hg incoming
```

If you are still having issues, you should specify better how your proxy was set up. Because, on Ubuntu 16.04 with Mercurial 4.0.2, it works instantly.

One more thing, Mercurial paths (see command `hg paths`).
If your repository is something like:

```
default = https://host.com.something/repo
```

Everything should work, but if you are using SSH:

```
default = ssh://user@host.com.something/repo
```

Then, I doubt my answer will solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe you're reffering to "no_proxy" config, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I added some details about versions. However I'm still struggling

Comment: Ok, I did it: your solution was right, the problem was I wrote in the "no" directive the whole repo address instead on the domain. Now it works, thanks